# Problems when working around no 2 class extending

Tags: java, user-interface

The title is very confusing, I know.
I've wanted to make my own UI library in java using swing. I first decided to create a UIButton.

code (very simplified):

```
class UIButton extends JButton {
int x = DEFAULT_X, y = DEFAULT_Y;
int w = DEFAULT_w, h = DEFAULT_H;
UIButton(){
  super("Text Here");
  super.setBounds(x,y,w,h);
}

void setPosition(int x, int y){
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  super.setBounds(x,y,w,h);
}

void setDimensions(int w, int h){
  this.w = w;
  this.h = h;
  super.setBounds(x,y,w,h);
}

void enableMe(){
  super.setVisible(false);
  super.setEnabled(false);
  super.setFocusable(false);
}
...
}
```

Then I realized that code would repeat because every UI component needs setPosition, setDimensions and enableMe() so I made a class UIComponent, but you can't write `class UIButton extends JButton, UIComponent {...}` :(
Then I made an interface UIComponentInter where I put all the default methods, that worked fine with the enableMe() method but not for the rest.
UIComponentInter (had to workaround if subclass isn't part of JComponent):

```
default void enableMe(){
  if(!(this instanceof JComponent)) return;
  JComponent component = (JComponent) this;
  component.setVisible(true);
  component.setEnabled(true);
  component.setFocusable(true);
}
```

setPosition() method requires variables x and y, but every variable in an interface is final and static. 
Currently I use the UIComponent class to control the bahavior and the UIButton class acts as a proxy to the UIComponent but I still have to copy-paste a lot of code to add new UI elements.

Comment: Use composition rather than inheritance - make your class have an instance field of type `JButton` instead

Answer (score -1):

> Use composition rather than inheritance - make your class have an instance field of type JButton instead – [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11882002/user)